# Array looping in R

Tags: arrays, r, loops

Suppose the following code which aims to do the following:
For different values of `g` i want to create an array with tables which are filled from the results of the `Vijk` function. So what happens is that for `g=1` the algorithm runs and fills in the `VijkArray`, then I want to insert this array into `result.1[3,2,1:3]`. For `g=2` the same procedure, but now fill up `result.1[3,2,4:6], etc. My issue is how to make this final step from happening, because what happens now is that the first 3 parts of the array are keep getting overwritten, i understand why, but fail to overcome it.

```
g=c(0.65,0.70,0.75,0.80,0.85)
result.1 <- array(0, dim = c(3,2,15))
VijkArray <- array(0,dim=c(3,2,3))
for(t in 1:length(g)){

  for (i in 1:3) {
    for (j in 1:3) {
      for (q in 1:2) {
        x <-xnew1[i,q,j]
        VijkArray[i,q,j]<-Vijk(x,q) #call Vijk function and update the criterion value accordingly
        result.1[i,q,j]<-VijkArray[i,q,j]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Example .Rdata environment to use](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ka4sn6wb284olcv/Test1.RData?dl=0)

```
>result.1

, , 1


          [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.000000  0.5285917
[2,] -1.433881 -0.5823365
[3,] -1.866261 -1.1893313

, , 2

           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.5823365  0.4061262
[2,] -1.6576946 -0.9137839
[3,] -2.0629455 -1.4338807

, , 3

           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.9137839  0.2588162
[2,] -1.8662608 -1.1893313
[3,] -2.2500000 -1.6576946

, , 4

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    0

, , 5

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    0

, , 6

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    0

, , 7

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    0

, , 8

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    0

, , 9

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    0

, , 10

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    0

, , 11

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    0

, , 12

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    0

, , 13

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    0

, , 14

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    0

, , 15

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
[3,]    0    0
```

You will notice that all results keep being reported in the first 3 tables of the array. So for the 1st `g` the first 3 tables should be filled, then for the second `g` tables 4,5 and 6 should be filled and so on.

Comment: Can you please share more detail i.e. what is the content of g along with expected output? Your dropbox file is not visible.

Comment: Sure! Check now :)